# Versioning or create Delta of File

Tags: java, android, versioning, delta

I want to compare or get delta of two files that means if a file or directory has just been renamed or moved or changed into another folder will handle these operations like a deletion and subsequent file (re)creation, resulting in re-transmitting the entire file or even directory to the mirror location at the new location or with the new name or a file that made changes then how can i get that changes not the whole file.

How can i achieve this in java or android.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need something like [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync). There is a Java implementation 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/jazsync/ so you might want to look into that. I'm not sure how stable it is or how well it works with Android.

Comment: but i try this and i don't understand this jazsync if you have any example or implementation of code then please tell me. Thnx for help.